# All unique column combinations in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, combinations, python-itertools

thanks for reading.

I'm trying to create **all possible unique combinations of columns in a dataframe**. So, having columns A, B, C and D, the combinations would be **AB, AC, AD, BC, BD, ABC, ABD**.

```
A   B   C   D   AB   AC   AD ...
1   1   3   2   2    4    3
```

To accomplish this, I created a for loop:

```
for i, comb in enumerate(df_p.columns):
    for comb2 in df_p.columns[i:]:
        if (comb != comb2) & (comb not in comb2)):
            df_p[comb + ' + ' + comb2] = df_p[comb].astype('str') + ' + ' + df_p[comb2].astype("str")
            print(" comb: " + comb + " combines with comb2: " + comb2)
```

Basically the "comb" iterator starts in the first column (A), and the second iterator "comb2" starts the second column (B), creating AB, and moving on until all A combinations are created. Then, when comb goes to B, comb2 starts at C, and so on. The if conditions prevent things like A + A as well as A + BA (some errors I was having when testing this with a couple more columns in the df).

My problem now is regarding the reversed duplicates, like having "ABD" being created when iterator one is at letter A (and iterator two combines it with all columns) as well as "DBA" when iterator one is at D and iterator two does all combinations.

In my research I have tried using itertools combinations as well, like this: `set(itertools.combinations(df_p.columns, 2))` for combinations of 2 and so forth for every other possible combination, but then I was having troubles "mapping" the newly created column combinations (like AB) with the row values of my original df (which would be the row values of A + row values of B for this example).

I prefer the itertools option, as it allows for more control on how many combinations we want, and probably it is not so hard to map. Any thoughts?

Thank's in advance.

----------------------------------UPDATE-----------------------------------------

Just to clear things, I forgot to mention that the rows are strings. Here is a snippet of the real columns:

```
retired     nationality     region
   1         Portugal       Lisbon
```

So creating all combinations of just these 3 for example would be:

```
retired  nationality  region  retired + nationality   retired + region   (..)
   1      Portugal    Lisbon      1 + Portugal           1 + Lisbon
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, [`combinations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) and [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) with [`Series.add`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.add.html)

```
from itertools import combinations
from functools import reduce
```

---

```
cols = df.columns.copy()
for i in range(2, len(cols) + 1):
    for names in combinations(cols, i):
        df[''.join(names)] = reduce(lambda cum_serie, new_serie_name: \
                                    cum_serie.add(df[new_serie_name]),
                                    names[1:],
                                    df[names[0]])


print(df)
```

**Output**

```
   A  B  C  D  AB  AC  AD  BC  BD  CD  ABC  ABD  ACD  BCD  ABCD
0  1  1  3  2   2   4   3   4   3   5    5    4    6    6     7
```

**EDIT**

```
df = df.rename(columns=str).astype(str)
cols = df.columns.copy()
for i in range(2, len(cols) + 1):
    for names in combinations(cols, i):
        df[' + '.join(names)] = reduce(lambda cum_serie, new_serie_name: \
                                    cum_serie.str.cat(df[new_serie_name], ' + '),
                                    names[1:],
                                    df[names[0]])
print(df)

   A  B  C  D  A + B  A + C  A + D  B + C  B + D  C + D  A + B + C  A + B + D  \
0  1  1  3  2  1 + 1  1 + 3  1 + 2  1 + 3  1 + 2  3 + 2  1 + 1 + 3  1 + 1 + 2   

   A + C + D  B + C + D  A + B + C + D  
0  1 + 3 + 2  1 + 3 + 2  1 + 1 + 3 + 2
```

Comment: for me question a bit unclear, but I think OP need this, +1

Comment: Thanks for your help ansev. Probably my mistake not to refer that the rows are strings, so instead of having 1 below column A, I would have names for example. So the combo between A ("John") and B ("Lisbon") would be a new column "A + B" with row value of "John + Lisbon". After trying your solution I'm getting a "must be str, not float" error, pointing me to the "df[''.join(names)] bit

Comment: You are welcome maybe we need convert names of columns to `str`.
There may also be a mixture of str and non-str columns, We can start with `df=df.rename(columns=str).astype(str)` and then `cols = df.columns.copy()` ...

Comment: Wow, amazing! It does seem to combine every column in the provided dataframe. Just for formatting issues, how you would you add a " + " between the combined variables and their respective rows? Like column name being "variable1 + variable2" and rows being "row1 + row2", instead of variable1variable2?

Comment: I think you would need :         `df[' + '.join(names)] = reduce(lambda cum_serie, new_serie_name: \
                                    cum_serie.str.cat(df[new_serie_name], ' + '),
                                    names[1:],
                                    df[names[0]])`. here it is similar to `cum_serie.add(' + ').add(df[new_serie_name])`

Comment: Done! Thank's a lot for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I think using `combinations` is the right way to go about it.

First create a list of column combinations:

`col_combs = list(combinations(df.columns, 2))`

And then to get a df just containing those columns for any given combination, convert the combination tuple into a list, and pass it to the dataframe.

```py
cols = list(col_combs[0]
comb_df = `df[col_combs)]
```

Below is a minimal example of how to store a separate dataframe for each combination of 2 columns:

```py
col_combs = list(combinations(df.columns, 2))

comb_dfs = []

for cols in col_combs:
    temp = df[list(cols)].copy()
    comb_dfs.append(temp)
```

To get it to work for greater combinations of columns, you'd just run several different `combinations` with the values you wanted, and gather all the results into one list before making the dataframes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Peritract. After creating the combinations in a list (col_combs), I'm still not managing to create a new df with all the combinations and their respective values. Grabbing what I commented on ansev's answer below, the original dataframe has only string values, so combining "A" with "B" would create a new column "A + B" with the row value of "A + B". If column A has row value of John and Mary and B has row value of Lisbon and Porto, column "A + B" would have "John + Lisbon" and "Mary + Porto" as rows.